# Learn C for programmers

Tags: c, makefile, compilation

I would like to learn how to work with C,

The things I have problems with are compilation and makefiles, not so much the C syntax. Most books deal mostly with the language, but what I'm looking for is more the other parts. What IDE and compiler do I use, and how do I use these.

Thank you very much!

Comment: If you can specify your host environment (Windows / Linux / ?) it will make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: I wonder which are other versions of C?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend gcc for the compiler and just a normal text editor for the ide. Compilation and working with makefiles is relatively simple, you could learn all you want by just googling it. I started out with vi and gcc. Now I use eclipse, netbeans, and gedit for when I am using c/c++.

Comment: When I am on linux `gcc` is the compiler of choice (obviously), but I really prefer `SciTE` to `gedit`.  Even better in my opinion is developing in Windows using `Notepad++` then just use `putty` to act as your terminal (and access `gcc` on a linux machine) or use `MinGW` for a native Windows compiler.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking at strictly C, than there is nothing probably better on a nix system than Vim and Make.

Programming isn't always easy. Struggle with it and learn.

If you don't mind more C++ than I would recommend the following:

I have also used [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) which is a free open source IDE available for *nix systems.

On Windows just use [Visual C++ Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/) which is also free.

Comment: others may argue there is probably nothing *worse* than vim (just kidding).

Comment: +1 For Visual C++ Express on Windows for beginners.

Comment: A modern build system such as [SCons](http://scons.org) is probably a good choice for new development (instead of make).

Answer (score 0):

Both Eclipse and Netbeans have functionality to develop and build C programs.

There's lots of tutorials e.g. [Getting Started With the NetBeans C/C++](http://cnd.netbeans.org/cnd-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

Much depends of the OS you actually use to compile. Really IDE and Makefiles are not C related and there is books about them. I would suggest to try a minimalist environment (any text editor and compiling from command line) to understand what is under the hood, then go for a full featured IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gcc`, write a Makefile for every project you make (even a small hello world program), and use `gdb` to debug. As for editing code, use whatever you enjoy typing in.